# Rownum cause results to show results in undorder manner

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a query which has the `rownum >=15` at the end.
When I run this query this shows results correctly which means its shows all the 15 rows one by one and the order of the row shown is not changed.Example of the results shown in order :1,2,3,

But,when I remove the `rownum >=15`from the query the results is not shown in order 1,2,3 instead the resuls is shown in order 1,3,2.

Any idea from you guys will be really helpful for me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Is this MySQL or Oracle?  All you're going to get out of this question is "If you want your results ordered, use `ORDER BY`," just so you know where this is headed, but if you post your query somebody will be able to point out exactly -what- `ORDER BY` clause you're going to need.

Comment: if you post the sample data and the query you were trying.. it would be easy for us to help

Comment: The query is too big,let me see whether i can able to post it

Comment: Are you generating rownum in some subquery and the using rownum >= 15? or just using it with some query? According to me, rownum >=15 is never going to give you results in Oracle unless you have defined "rownum" a column alias after shorting in some sub-query.

Comment: I have given order by in the subquery but I am using the rownum in outer query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been a long lasting query from many.

Reasons for such behaviour can be analysed as below.

Your database must be in *serial mode*.

Oracle documentation says:

> Oracle Database inserts data into a table in one of two ways:
>
> - serial mode: During *conventional INSERT* operations, the database reuses free space in the table, interleaving newly inserted data with existing data.
> - parallel mode: During *direct-path INSERT* operations, the database appends the inserted data after existing data in the table. Free space in the existing data is not reused, and referential integrity constraints are ignored. These procedures combined can enhance performance.

In conventional mode, the following records

```
insert into users
  values( 1, 'Elvis' ), ( 2, 'Jackson' ), ( 3, 'Madonna' );
```

*may* result in following order of storage.
Basic *select* would hence result the same.

```
2   Jackson
1   Elvis
3   Madonna
```

In *direct-path INSERT*, data is appended to the end of the table, rather than using existing space currently allocated to the table.

To force using *direct-path INSERT*, we use [*/*+ APPEND */*](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50901) hint.

```
insert /*+ APPEND */ into users
  values( 1, 'Elvis' ), ( 2, 'Jackson' ), ( 3, 'Madonna' );
```

This *will* append the rows at the end of the table.
Basic *select* would hence fetch the records *in the order of insertion*.

```
1   Elvis
2   Jackson
3   Madonna
```

But what happens to those records that were added before opting for *direct path mode*? They exist on the same locations while inserted. To resolve such issue we have to use any of following *order by* options:

- **RowID** -- address id of the row inserted. (My observation is that it is always sequential for each of the tables). Use `order by rowid`.
- **Indexed** field -- say, `order by user_id`
- [**INDEX hint**](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/sql_elements006.htm#SQLRF50405) -- Define an index on an appropriate field and use this hint to fetch records in the order defined for the index.

---

On your data, there is no option but chose an appropriate ordering solution and retrieve it.

Comment: The order that rows are inserted is completely irrelevant to the question of what order they should be returned by a query. The only accurate part of this answer is that they need to add an `order by` clause.

Comment: OP's doubt was why if an order by is not used they are not returned in the order of insertion?

Comment: Not sure where you get that idea Ravinder, the OP is just asking about two queries and why they return results in different orders.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: You are right that OP has not used the words *in the order of insertion*. But, when read it, I realised that I too faced similar issue earlier and that was *truely* observed on order of insertion. And hence is my explanation in the answer.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: And OP should also clarify if my assumption on his data was correct.

Comment: btw `order by rowid` and using an index hint are *not* ways to solve this problem. Also, an `order by` clause does not have to be on indexed fields necessarily. There is one, and only one solution to ordering, and that is an `order by` clause. The rest is trivia.

Comment: Well, *Index hint* is pre ordered and we need not apply an *order by*.

Comment: No, adding an index hint will not guarantee order. That might happen in practice depending on the query plan, but without an order by clause, Oracle can (**and has**) quite easily use a different execution plan which will *use the index*, but not return the results in your expected order.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp: OK. I have not seen this happening yet on my attempts. But will remember. Most of the times I used *an index hint with asc/desc*.